# Wifi network is just weird (slow connection, some networks never shown, sometimes disconnects)

Tags: wireless, 22.04, dell, inspiron

I'm not sure what the problem is. Everything was laggy and bad before, but suddenly it went from bad to worse.

[image: screenshot of wifi]

hilt is my main network that was working fine, but now the connection is slow and it seems like the network bars are low although it's not that far away. The other network is just me tethering the main network from my mobile. There are at least dozen other networks of my neighbors that should be available, but they are not.

Recently I changed the housing of the laptop.

Ubuntu 22.04
Dell Inspiron 5559

Comment: "recently I changed the housing of the laptop" Are you quite certain that *both* antenna connections are firmly snapped in place on the wireless card?